# Error when registering user using login via microsoft Account

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm configuring the social login in my application using a Microsoft account. At the moment, the user is able to authenticate but when he press the register button in /Account/ExternalLoginCallback a validation error shows up (the UserId is required).

[image: Error shown]

After debugging the application, the error appears as show here

[image]

Finally, despite the errors the user is still saved in the database (and with a user id).

[image]

I find this quite strange. Do you have any idea what might be happening?

UPDATE: As requested by the comments bellow, here are some of the information that might be helpful.

This image shows that the user in fact gets an userId before throwing the exception.

[image]

And here is the configuration code. I honestly didn't change much, except for the clientId and key. The clientId and Key are removed for obvious reasons.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

namespace EmpleoDotNet
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
            // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
                clientId: "[ClientId]",
                clientSecret: "[ClientSecret]");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //   consumerKey: "",
            //   consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //   appId: "BLAH",
            // appSecret: "BLAH");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the field UserId in your form ? are you sure your form passes  a value to the controller?

Comment: I don't. In fact, the UserId is generated by the method UserManager.CreateUserAsync(user). That's why it shows in the database.

Comment: When you debug , do you get any value from the view for UserID?

Comment: Please post the code that configures the external identity providers (obfuscating your keys, of course)

Comment: I have updated the post as requested.

Comment: Have you added any custom fields to the ApplicationUser class?

Comment: I am commenting from my mobile so don't have access to code, but I think the default implementation should have 'id' field and not 'UserId'.

Comment: This should be pretty easy to figure out.  Wrap the call to `AddLoginAsync()` in a try catch block.  Log the exception, but you'll also be able to put a breakpoint in the catch block.  I'd suggest that your exception will have an inner exception that details the Entity Validation that you are receiving.  At a guess, I'd say that a value that is required in the database is not being received inside `info.Login`